# How to replace option menu item in the toolbar to another option menu item when clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have an edit menu item for a Textview on the toolbar, when I click on the edit icon, myTextView would be editable, after that I want to remove edit menu and replace it with save menu item, because when I click on the edit menu, it will be no longer in use. In this way the text would be updated to the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method for switching menu items and call it inside on `onOptionsItemSelected`

**method for switching menuItem**

```
void switchMenuItem(int id)
{
    MenuItem save_item = menu.findItem(id_save);
    MenuItem edit_item = menu.findItem(id_edit);
    
    if (id == id_edit) {
        edit_item.setVisible(false);
        save_item.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        edit_item.setVisible(true);
        save_item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

**calling method**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switchMenuItem(item.getItemId())
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll post the answer that how I fixed.

Comment: Welcome @Omer123 and If my solution helped accept the answer and your solution is good too 

Comment: I think your answer is not the exact answer I was looking for, but I have got a rough idea regarding my question. Anyhow I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved for everyone wondering how I did it.

Created a boolean variable named isEdit above onCreate() method and set the value to false;

```
boolean isEdit = false;

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_save_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

edit_save_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:title="edit"
    android:icon="@drawable/edit"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:title="save"
    android:icon="@drawable/check"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
        // do stuff

isEdit = true;
 invalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;

        case R.id.save:
        // do some other stuff
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> finish(), 500);
          break;

    }
        return true;
    }

 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(isEdit) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.save).setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;

}
```